# pine script RSI strategy on trading view not working?

Tags: pine-script

I want my RSI to go long at any price under the 30 RSI but it just enters at random prices? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="Draft", overlay=false, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, initial_capital = 25000)

//Create stop-loss inputs
sl_inp = input(0.5, title='Stop Loss %')/100
tp_inp = input(4.5, title='Take Profit %')/100
stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)
take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)

//Create RSI inputs
rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
rsiOverbought = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", type=input.integer, defval=70)
rsiOversold = input(title="RSI Oversold Level", type=input.integer, defval=30)

// Determine long and short conditions
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)
Long = rsiOversold
exitLong = (close < stop_level) or (close > take_level)

// Submit orders
start = timestamp(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2021, 7, 1, 0, 0)

if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = Long, alert_message = "Buy!")
    strategy.close("Long", when = exitLong)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to put RSI in your code.

```
Rsi = rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
Long = Rsi <= rsiOversold
```